# How to determine if a dataframe is Pandas or Spark?

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, dataframe

I pass a dataframe to a function. Sometimes it is Pandas dataframe, and sometimes it is a Spark dataframe. My function will need to act accordingly. Is there a simple method, such as df.isPandas(), to determine if a dataframe (received as "df") is a Pandas dataframe or a Spark dataframe? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about `type(df)`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `isinstance` :

```
if isinstance(df, pd.DataFrame):
    print('pandas')
else:
    print('spark')
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to check `df.schema.names`. This is only on Spark. Actually there are multiple other differences like `.show()` as well. Might be a good interview question :)